# ValueError: Items of feature_columns must be a _DenseColumn

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two features, the first one with shape 39 and the second one with shape 20 and both of them are numerical.
I want to create a cross feature between them so I did the following steps:

```
# Convert to numerical
feat_1 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col1', shape=(39,)) 
feat_2 = tf.feature_column.numeric_column('col2', shape=(20,)) 
# Bucketize numerical columns
buck_1 = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(feat_1, boundaries = [1,2,3])
buck_1 = tf.feature_column.bucketized_column(feat_2, boundaries = [1,2,3])
# cross both of them 
crossed = tf.feature_column.crossed_column(set([buck_1_, buck_2 ]), hash_bucket_size=1000)
```

When I train the model, it gives me an error : 
Items of feature_columns must be a _DenseColumn.

Would anyone please help me understand the issue!

B.S. I trained the model using all the feature and it was fine but if I added the crossed feature it gives me the error?